# Outlook profiles keep becoming corrupt using Goolge Apps Email

Tags: google-workspace, microsoft-outlook

I'm having a ongoing issue with one of my clients using google apps and outlook sync. Every now and then it gives me error "Cannot open your default e-mail folders. The information store could not be opened". The strange thing is i can open the pst through outlook using another profile.
I have also found that when this happens the google sync icon isnt running in the system tray. So I have to create another profile and sync again to make it work.

Did anyone come across same kind of issue before?